# MVC BeginForm No Data Posted

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC BeginForm with code below, i cannot get the value fpr input controls in my controller. am i doing anytyhing wrong here?

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateApp", "App",
new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "my-modal-dialog", OnBegin = "Dialog.Closing()", OnSuccess = "Dialog.Close()" },
         new
         {
             @class = "appform"
         }
        ))
{

   <input id="newAppName" type="text" size="35" value="" />
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Application.AppName);     

<input type="submit" value="Start App" class="demo-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all" />


}


My Controller looks like this
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateApp(AppContent app, string newAppName)
    {

    }
```

Comment: You have 2 inputs. The first one has no name attribute and will therefore not work. The second one (Razor generated) will have a name attribute with the value "Application.AppName".

Comment: agree with @reinder, but wonder if Application is of type AppContent. Thats what I assumed.

Comment: In which case your answer should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing

```
<input id="newAppName" type="text" size="35" value="" />
```

to

```
<input name="newAppName" type="text" size="35" value="" />
```